# Dynamic URL Prefix UI Router AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have an e-commerce site which has a multishop setup. In addition, there's an additional hierarchy added wherein a shop belongs to an account.

We define scopes using the URL such that when the following URL is visited. It will show the orders for all the shops for the account.

```
http://somehost.com/#/orders
```

To view orders for a particular shop. The URL is prefixed with 'shop/' plus the shop id like the following:

```
http://somehost.com/#/shop/1/orders

http://somehost.com/#/shop/2/orders
```

My problem is how to set up the router. I've set it up like below to handle the account level URLs but I don't want to duplicate the code below just to define the URLs for the shop URLs. Any ideas how to achieve the above?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui-router'])

.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
       .state('orders', {
          url: '/orders',
          template: 'views/order.html'
          controller: 'OrdersCtrl'
       })
       .state('orders.view', {
          url: '{order_id:[0-9]{1,6}}'
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the params option:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui-router'])

.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
       .state('root', {
          url: '/',
          params: {
              shop_id: {
                 value: ''
                 squash: true
              }
          },
          template: '<div ui-view></div>'
       })
       .state('root.orders', {
          url: '/{shop_id:[0-9]{0-2}}/orders',
          template: 'views/order.html'
          controller: 'OrdersCtrl'
       })
       .state('root.orders.view', {
          url: '{order_id:[0-9]{1,6}}',
       });
});
```

The only caveat is I need to define a root state.